# Add an icon on the date from custom calendar if matched from the database's date

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm trying to figure out on how can I possibly put an icon on the day cell if its date has a match from the database.
Let's say I have rows of data which includes the date, now if i could ever compare the date from the database and all the dates included in the custom calendar, all of the dates in the calendar are matched from the database's dates will have an icon appear. Maybe something a code like if conditions or what is might your best suggestion or you could give me an idea on how to do it.

Comment: You can use `if-else` block to do that.

Comment: yes I know I could use that but I don't know how I would implement it, and what are the logic codes should I use.